# How to strip info from every JSON file under the same folder using BASH?

Tags: json, bash

Let's say I have `firstJSON.json secondJSON.json ...` under the same folder, and each file looks like

```
{
    "obj1":"item1",
    "obj2":"item2"
}
```

Now I want to strip `item1` and `item2`, then put them into one file `outFile`, I have written the following code to do that:

```bash
function strip {
    item1=$(cat $1 | grep 'obj1' | cut -d '"' -f4)
    item2=$(cat $1 | grep 'obj2' | cut -d '"' -f4)
    name=$(echo $1 | cut -d '.' -f1)
    echo $name':'$item1':'$item2 >> ./outFile 
}
```

but how do I use this piece of code to strip info from every JSON file and then put them all into `outFile`?

Comment: can you show what is the expected output? Note also that there is a tool to parse JSON properly: [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: @fedorqui the expected output looks like `FirstJSON:item1:item2`

Comment: thanks for recommending the tool, but now i need to process multiple files under a specific folder, my code deals with only one single file at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use with for loop as below;

```
for j in *.json; do
item1=$(cat $j | grep 'obj1' | cut -d '"' -f4)
item2=$(cat $j | grep 'obj2' | cut -d '"' -f4)
name=$(echo $j | cut -d '.' -f1)
echo $name':'$item1':'$item2 >> ./outFile 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A single grep on all files is enough piped into an awk munger

```
files=$*
grep -HPo '^ +"obj\d+" *: *"\K[^"]+' $files|
awk -F: '
src == $1 {
  printf(":%s", $2)
  next
}
{
  if(src) printf("\n")
  src=$1
  f1=gensub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",1,$1)
  printf("%s:%s", f1, $2)
}
END {printf("\n")}
'
```